# How to group by two conditions in rails 3 and loop through them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, group-by

Ok so I have a sale model that

```
recent_sales = Sale.recent
 => [#<Sale id: 7788, contact_id: 9988, purchasing_contact_id: 876, event_id: 988, #<BigDecimal:7fdb4ac06fe8,'0.0',9(18)>, fulfilled_at: nil, skip_print: nil, convention_id: 6, refund_fee: #<BigDecimal:7fdb4ac06de0,'0.0',9(18)>, processing: false>, #<Sale id: 886166, , contact_id: 7775,

recent_sales.count
=> 32
```

I know i can do this

```
grouped_sales = recent_sales.group_by(&:contact_id).map {|k,v| [k, v.length]}
=> [[9988, 10], [7775, 22]]
```

But what i really need is not just grouping on contact_id but also event_id so the final results looks like this

```
=> [[9988, 988, 5], [9988, 977, 5], [7775, 988, 2], [7775, 977, 20]]
```

so i have the event_id and the grouping is splitting them up correctly...any ideas on how to do this

I tried

```
 recent_sales.group('contact_id, event_id').map {|k,v| [k, k.event, v.length]}
```

but no go

Comment: did you try `group(['contact_id','event_id'])`?

Comment: here's great answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14660644/group-by-in-rails-by-2-or-more-attributes

Answer (score 12):

```
grouped_sales = recent_sales.group_by { |s| [s.contact_id, s.event_id] }
                .map { |k,v| [k.first, k.last, v.length] }
```

Answer (score 8):

Simply, try

```
group(['contact_id','event_id'])
```

It worked for me. So, I posted as answer to help others as well.

Answer (score 1):

Ask the database to do the grouping

```
grouped_sales = recent_sales.group([:contact_id, :event_id]).count
```

the result is a hash each key is an array of the contact and event id, and the value is the count.

So if you want arrays of three

```
grouped_sales = recent_sales.group([:contact_id, :event_id]).count.map{ |k,v| k << v }
```

Comment: This works. Any idea how to get an associated model's value, e.g. `name` of the `contact` or `date` of an `event` (in the query result itself)?