# group_by in rails by 2 or more attributes

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, group-by

I have a `@bunch` of models returned as an array

each model has the attributes - `commentable_id` and `commentable_type` (polymorphic association)

I want to group the models by commentable, but if I do

```
@bunch.group_by(&:commentable)
```

it also fetches the commentable from the database, which is not needed.

I can do `@bunch.group_by(&:commentable_id)` but this will cause some confusions since there can be several types of commentable models

Is there a way to `group_by` `commentable_id` AND `commentable_type`?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Why not do:

```
@bunch.group_by{|e| [e.commentable_id, e.commentable_type]}
```

Comment: Thanks - how would I read values from a hash with two keys though?

Comment: `.each{|(id, type), value| .. }` @Qasim

Comment: @FrederikSpang, if taking this a step forward, what is the best way to obtain associated model values, e.g. comment's author name or comment create date etc.?

Comment: Note you can also splat an array of keys to do the same as in the answer. `[{id: 'maisy', type: 'cat'}].group_by { |x| x.values_at(*%i[id type]) }`. Probably easier on the eyes in most cases, where these literal values would be nice semantic variables.

Comment: Just a note: group_by is part of Enumerable, but can be invoked on ActiveRecord::Relation objects since the Relation is mixed in with Enumerable.